# How do I write a Java adapter for Oracle GoldenGate?

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

According to this whitepaper [1], Oracle GoldenGate for Big Data

> > ... also includes Oracle GoldenGate for Java,
> >     which enables customers to easily deliver to additional big data systems and support
> >     specific use cases that their environment demands.

What is the function signature for these plugins?

[1] http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/data-integration/goldengate-for-big-data-ds-2415102.pdf

Comment: I'm might miss something but the document you linked doesn't contain the sentence you quoted. Actually "environment demands" is already not found in that PDF. Did you used some other link? Also have you looked at https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/gg121211/gg-adapter/GADAD/intro_java.htm#GADAD414 It looks like what "Java Adapter" does is it provides some means to integrate with your JMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate to Java please use one of two GoldenGate modules:

- GoldenGate for BigData - has ready to use adapters to replicate directly to HDFS, HBase, Flume, Kafka, Cassandra, MongoDB, JDBC. Details in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/bd123010/gg-bd/index.html)
- GoldenGate for Application Adapters - allows to write directly to flat file and JMS. Details in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/gg121211/gg-adapter/index.html)

There are also [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/gg121211/gg-adapter/GADAD/apdx_examples.htm) in the documentation.